# The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Tags: php

The issue I am facing while uploading the zipped own written plugin from wordpress admin panel **The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature**
in the latest version 5.3.1 I don't want to change even a single line of wordpress core. Can I add some functionality to my wordpress plugin to fix the error ...thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I figure out the issue is with xampp server php.ini file settings.I am using 64 bit windows 7 and xampp 1.7.7 .I tried with upload_max_filesize = 100M restarted xammp but yet not worked. Any idea to fix this issue???

Answer (score 1):

you can solved it by commenting out mbstring.func_overload in my php.ini file:

```
; mbstring.func_overload = 7
```

and restart your server. You should also check your webspace.